# Привязка SteamID к определенному человеку

Tags: c#

**Что можете посоветовать по мимо HWID?**
Его чуть позже буду реализовывать.

В данный момент проверяю по asn по get запросу к сайту - но думаю это не безопасно да и время занимает прилично на примере `https://iphub.info` не реклама

Comment: A steamID is a unique identifier used to identify a Steam account -- он и так привязан к человеку, а точнее к логину. Что вы пытаетесь сделать то?

Comment: @Monk я не говорю по Steam игры - имею ввиду пиратские версии игры - та что у меня игра была раньше в стим.Теперь она больше там не находиться,а привязка осталась